# Spring Data MongoDB aggregation - get amount of results

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I am a dummy in using spring aggregations.
I do have this entity document:

```
@Document(collection = "DocumentFile")
public class DocumentFile {

    private String projectId;
    private String originalFileName;
```

and I will get the amount of **documentFile**s which have the same **projectId** grouped by **originalFileName** (so DocumentFile's with same name should only be counted once)

This is my approach but I don't know how to get now the result/amount.

```
final Aggregation agg = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("projectId").in(projectId)),
        group("originalFileName").count().as("amountOfDocumentFiles"));
```

Comment: Do you want the count of various originalFileName for a specific projectId? Can you add a sample document of this collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that aggregate present in the post is correct. Here is the sample code to execute the aggregate using MongoOperations and get the result.

In my project, I get the MongoOperations object like this.

```
public MongoOperations getMongoConnection() {

        return (MongoOperations) new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringMongoConfig.class)
                .getBean("mongoTemplate");
    }
```

**Execute aggregate and get results:-**

```
Aggregation aggregate = newAggregation(match(Criteria.where("projectId").in(projectId)),
        group("originalFileName").count().as("amountOfDocumentFiles"));

AggregationResults<DocumentFile> documentFileAggregate = mongoOperations.aggregate(aggregate,
                "DocumentFile", DocumentFile.class);

if (documentFileAggregate != null) {
    System.out.println("Output ====>" + documentFileAggregate.getRawResults().get("result"));
    System.out.println("Output ====>" + documentFileAggregate.getRawResults().toMap());
}
```